# Why does assigning value to one variable update another variable?

Tags: php

I have a code snippet that looks like this:

```
var_dump($download2);
$this->download->filename = $download2->filename.'.'.$ext;
$this->download->filepath = $this->tmpDir.'/'.$this->download->filename;
var_dump($download2);
```

My first `var_dump` return this:

```
object(stdClass)#730 (2) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(10) "ol8kw2q55b"
  ["filepath"]=>
  string(66) "a/path/storage/photos/tmp/ol8kw2q55b"
}
```

The second `var_dump` returns this:

```
object(stdClass)#730 (2) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(15) "ol8kw2q55b.jpeg"
  ["filepath"]=>
  string(71) "a/path/storage/photos/tmp/ol8kw2q55b.jpeg"
}
```

Why is `$this->download->filename = $download2->filename.'.'.$ext;` updating my `$download2` variable (if I remove that line both `var_dump` will return same value)?

---

My class looks like this (stripped some code):

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    protected $download;

    public function download($url) {
        $filename = $this->newHash();
        $this->download = (object)[
            'filename' => $filename,
            'filepath' => $this->tmpDir.'/'.$filename
        ];

        return $this->download;
    }

    public function addExtension($download2) {
        $ext = $this->allowedMimes[$mimeType];
        var_dump($download2);
        $this->download->filename = $download2->filename.'.'.$ext;
        $this->download->filepath = $this->tmpDir.'/'.$this->download->filename;
        var_dump($download2);

        return $this->download;
    }
}
```

I run it with this:

```
$class = new MyClass;
$var = $class->download("http://...");
$class->addExtension($var);
```

Comment: Because you append the `$ext` to your `download2?`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown he wasn't asking if it does.

Comment: @1ntello I'm appending `$ext` to `$download2->filename` but I'm not updating the `$download2` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird,

Can you please paste all the class file here?

I want to know where the $download2 variable come from . Maybe $this->download is loaded by reference from $download2 or something.

Trying to test the code individually with the snippets that I have gives this result :

```
var_dump($download2);
$this->download->filename = $download2->filename.'.'.$ext;
$this->download->filepath = $this->tmpDir.'/'.$this->download->filename;
var_dump($download2);
```

outputs :

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(4) "mama"
  ["filepath"]=>
  string(3) "dir"
}
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(4) "mama"
  ["filepath"]=>
  string(3) "dir"
}
```

Addition :

The following line : 
$var = $class->download("http://...");

Actually returns the $this->download variable, and after that

I see that you are passing it to the second method :

$class->addExtension($var);

So, the actual download2 it's the same as $this->download object.

The first var_dump() outputs the first values of $this->download

object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(8) "XDEFEFEQ"
  ["filepath"]=>
  string(9) "/XDEFEFEQ"
}

And since the $this->download is altered , automatically , $download2 variable is altered automatically.

Comment: "references" came to my mind too, but he have used `&` so it is hard to do it aciddentally. [PHP Reference Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign)

Comment: I guess it has something to do with what you're saying. I changed so `download()` returns `$this` and then let `addExtension()` use that instead. Thanks.